# What is pro bono?

Tags: legal-terms, lawyer, fees

I heard someone say;
"I used to work with you for free. Now I'm gonna do it pro bono"
And I thought he just repeated himself. But I want clarity. So what does pro bono actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that "for free" is simply "for free", but *[pro bono publico](http://www.americanbar.org/groups/probono_public_service/policy/aba_model_rule_6_1.html)* refers to a subset of free work aimed at certain recipients, specifically those unable to pay, or charitable, civic etc. organizations on behalf of such people, or (to a lesser extent) a worthy organization of limited means for free or reduced rates. So working for Bill Gates for free would not be *pro bono* work, since he has no problem with means.

Answer (score 1):

"Pro bono publico" == For the good of the public.

It's normal usage is in the context of legal services provided for free, as in:

http://www.probononj.org